# how to debug goroutine in vscode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goroutine, delve

consider the small snippet below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
            fmt.Println("A:", i)
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
            fmt.Println("B:", i)
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

in delve, we can easily switch between goroutines using the commands like

```
goroutine
goroutine <id>
goroutine <id> <command>
```

and if i want run step by step in goroutine 1, just use the command

```
goroutine 1 next
```

In vscode, it seems the only way to deal with goroutines is the call stack, however, it seems that this is the internal threads in go runtime, not the goroutines, so how can i focus the running process in the specified goroutine?

Answer (score 2):

> so how can i focus the running process in the specified goroutine?

[vscode-go issue 1797](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1797) should bring a possible solution:

> For example, when debugging a simple hello world program, 5 different goroutines appear in the callstack:
>
> [image: Program stopped on a breakpoint in main.go:]
>
> This proposal is to (by default) only show the user goroutines in the call stack. When using this new default, the call stack for hello world will only show a single goroutine, as would be expected from a simple program with no concurrency:
>
> [image: unique goroutine]

It just (Oct. 2021) has been submitted in [CL 359402](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/vscode-go/+/359402) (CL = Change List: a set of commits/patches)

> ### package.json: add config to hide system goroutines in debug
>
> This change includes the configuration for hiding the system goroutines in a debug session

Comment: So: not yet delivered, but might be in 0.30 or 0.31.

Answer (score -4):

Jetbrains have introduced a cool new feature for debugging go-routines in its IDE. Please follow this [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/03/03/how-to-find-goroutines-during-debugging/) to take a look

It uses feature of labels provided by pprof and is not exclusive to jetbrains I suppose although they might have tweaked it for usability. Here is an [article](https://rakyll.org/profiler-labels/) on lables so that you can try to implement it in vscode also.